# how to enable to location?

Tags: android, location

Hi in the below code i am connecting devices via bluetooth and location.
For first time is it asking for permission to turn on the location but it is not enabling the location.

can any one please help me how to enable the location automaticatically like buetooth in the below code

for example:In bluetooth, it is asking for the permission and turning it on.
but for location for first time it is asking for permission but it is not enabling the location.

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_device);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        initToolBar();
        mBleDevices = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(this);
        mDeviceListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mDeviceListView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        mDeviceListView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                showProgressDialog();
                List<BluetoothDevice> bluetoothDevices = mAdapter.getBluetoothDevices();
                if (bluetoothDevices != null) {
                    if (bluetoothDevices.size() > position) {
                        BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = bluetoothDevices.get(position);
                        if (bluetoothDevice != null) {
                            String address = bluetoothDevice.getAddress();
                            mBleService.connect(address);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
        final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BleService.ACTION_DEVICE_FOUND);
        intentFilter.addAction(BleService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BleService.ACTION_GAT_CONNECTING);
        intentFilter.addAction(BleService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BleService.ACTION_GAT_SERVICE_DISCOVERED);
        registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, intentFilter);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        , Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
            }
        } else {
            if (mServiceConnection != null) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 101);
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, BleService.class);
            bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    }
    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        }
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            mBleService = ((BleService.LocalBinder) iBinder).getLeService();
            if (mBleService != null) {
                mBleService.scanLeDevice(true);
                mScanStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mScanStatus.setText(R.string.scanning_device);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 101) {
            if (mBleService != null) {
                mBleService.scanLeDevice(true);
            }
        }
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case BleService.ACTION_DEVICE_FOUND:
                    BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BleService.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    if (mBleDevices != null) {
                        if (!mBleDevices.contains(device)) {
                            mBleDevices.add(device);
                            mAdapter.udpateBluetoothDevices(mBleDevices);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case BleService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "!Action gat connected...");
                    mBleService.scanLeDevice(false);
                    mScanStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mScanStatus.setText(getString(R.string.connected));
                    break;
                case BleService.ACTION_GAT_CONNECTING:
                    mScanStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mScanStatus.setText(getString(R.string.connecting));
                    Log.d(TAG, "!Action Gat Connecting..");
                    break;
                case BleService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED:
                    mScanStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mScanStatus.setText(getString(R.string.disconnected));
                    mScanningProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mRefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "!Action Gat Disconnected..");
                    break;
                case BleService.ACTION_GAT_SERVICE_DISCOVERED:
                    boolean isOperator = mPref.getBoolean(Constants.IS_OPERATOR, false);
                    if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    if (isOperator) {
                        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(DeviceScanActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
                        startActivity(homeIntent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Intent lightControllIntent = new Intent(DeviceScanActivity.this, LightConfigurationActivity.class);
                        startActivity(lightControllIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    mScanStatus.setText(getString(R.string.discoveringService));
                    Log.d(TAG, "!Action Gat Discovering..");
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    private void initToolBar() {
        mRefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @OnClick(R.id.refresh)
    public void onClick() {
        mScanStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mScanningProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mBleDevices.clear();
        mAdapter.udpateBluetoothDevices(new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>());
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mServiceConnection != null) {
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        }
        if (mGattUpdateReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (mServiceConnection != null) {
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 101);
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, BleService.class);
                bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            } else {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can do this with google play services ... question was already asked here multiple times

Comment: can you please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can't enable location programmatically if device is not rooted.

Here is code how to ask user to enable location in Fragment:

```
 override fun checkLocationSettings() {
    if (activity != null) {
        locationSettingsTask.addOnFailureListener(activity!!) { exception ->
            if (exception is ResolvableApiException) {
                try {
                    exception.startResolutionForResult(activity,
                            REQUEST_CODE_CHECK_LOCATION_SETTINGS)
                } catch (ignore: Exception) {
                    // Empty
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHECK_LOCATION_SETTINGS) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            presenter.resolveCurrentLocation()
        }
    }
}
```